# What causes a javascript function to not run it's callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am doing some image classification through the ml-5 library. I wrote all the code for classification for obtaining predictions from models while I was testing. Now while integrating this to the main code, the callback of the function that classifies the image is not working. It isn't even throwing any error.

This is the call to the classifier function.

```
classifier.classify(img, function (err, result) {
                console.log("classification complete");
                console.log(err);
                console.log(result);
            });
```

Here `img` is the HTML Image Element that is passed for classification.
err and result are the params that the `classify()` function should return in its callback.

I have tried debugging and found that all values are normal while going inside the `classify()` function, but it simply doesn't execute its callback and it is skipped

Almost the same code was used while testing.

The function doesn't give any errors, simply ignores the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried debugging and found that all values are normal while going inside the classify() function, but it simply doesn't execute its callback and it is skipped

It is not skipped, it hasn't been called because `callback` only be called when `classify` completes.